# How to change .NET Core Identity [User] table primary key name from ID to smething else

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-identity

Implementing .NET Core Identity into my project I saw that the conventional way is to call the primary key of the [User] table "Id". Is there a way to change the name of that column?

Comment: Why do you want to change it in a first place?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: By default primary key of user entity in Identity is "Id". I would like to name it differently, as en example I would like to name it "UserId".

Comment: @FTezak Do you have explicit DbContext defined for Identity? or its using the default IdentityDbContext? I can propose a solution once you clarify this

Answer (score 0):

with ef core,  you could add colum attribute on the property to change the name in database as below:

[image: Model]

Result:

the migration class:

[image: migration]
database:

[image: database]